# UISearchController changing view after being pressed

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, uibutton, uisearchcontroller

I am currently creating my first Swift application, and I have a search bar implemented like

```
private func addSearchBar() {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    
    navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

Obviously there is no logic other than displaying the search bar, but I was curious if there was a way to make it so when a user pressed the search bar, it would just switch to another view. I have been able to successfully implement changing views with UIButtons, but I am unfamilair with UISearchController, and I would like it to act just like a UIButton if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set the search bar's delegate to your view controller. In your case

```
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
```

then conform to the **UISearchBarDelegate** and add the following method in order to detect when you tap the search bar.

```
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    // your code to show another view or view controller
}
```